# Google Analytics Event Tracker

Tags: html, google-analytics

I'm not receiving the "Click" Events information at the Google-Analytycs website, It makes around 3 days that I've been waiting..

My code looks like this:

```
<HEAD>
    <!-- Google Website Tracking -->
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-51234567-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- Google Event Tracking -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-51234567-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

.. Not Relevant code

</HEAD>
```

(I replaced some numbers of the UA code for making this post, but the lenght and the structure is the same)

Then, for tracking events i use this code:

```
<A HREF="LINK" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External Link', 'External Web', 'TEXT']);"><FONT size="5">TEXT</FONT></A>
```

Of course, LINK is a real link, and TEXT is the name of the Website.

When i go to the Google analytics Website, in `admin>Tracking Info>Tracking Code>` i get `Status: Receiving Data`. In that Website, i do get the pages views information and everything seems alright, but I'm not getting the "Clicks Event" information. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, but I don't think so because I've look everywhere!

Comment: did you try to look in the console for eventual errors ?

Comment: I was searching what the console is, but I'm not really sure of what is. Could you give me some help/hint about checking errors at the console? Thanks by the way!

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console